# tableView's commit method stops being called if editActionsForRowAt is present

Tags: ios

My tableView's commit method gets called fine when the user swipes and deletes a row, but if I attempt to customize the color/text of the action by using editActionsForRowAt then it stops being called.

Here's some code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
{
    return .delete
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
 // delete code goes here 
}
```

With the above code then tableView:commit will get called. But if I attempt to change the background color and text by adding the method below then it stops getting called.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
 {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Remove") { (action, indexPath) in
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return [delete]
 }
```

Why does adding the editActionsForRowAt method stop the commit method from getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `editActionsForRowAt` the `commit` function won't be called.  Instead of putting your code in the `commit` function, put it in the closure on the `UITableViewRowAction`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Remove") { (action, indexPath) in
         // delete code should go here instead
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return [delete]
}
```